# Selecting a device for CUDA debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, cuda, gpu

I've got a couple of Parallel Nsight compatible CUDA GPU's. The second (lower) one is connected to my monitor, and the first (upper) one is is set up as a PhysX accelerator. You can clearly see my configuration below.

Now in order to perform CUDA debugging with Nsight, I need to only run kernel code on the GPU not connected to the monitor. My computer is already setup for "headless debugging". Also below is a basic example of code I wish to execute on the other GPU:

```
// KernelCall.cu
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void kernel(void){}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is basically what do I need to put in this code so that it only executes on the other device and allow me to perform CUDA debugging?

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

Comment: In the NVML API (Part of the CUDA Tools SDK in CUDA 4.0) there is a method which allows you to check if a display is attached to a device: 
    nvmlDeviceGetDisplayMode(nvmlDevice_t device, nvmlEnableState_t *display);

However, the documentation in nvml.h says this function only works on Tesla and Quadro products, so it may not be much use to you!

The only alternative I can think of might be the NVIDIA Control Panel API. It seems like that should be able to tell you if there is a display attached, but I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the advice, I was not aware of this feature in the 4.0 toolkit. However, I'm pleased to say I simply connected my monitor to the first GPU and used cudaSetDevice(1) at the beginning of all my code. I used HWMonitor to look at GPU temperatures, and indeed the animated programs do seem to be raising the temperature of the 2nd GPU. I also got CUDA debugging off Parallel Nsight working perfectly thanks to the very clear instructions put up by NVIDIA, so everything is fine now. Thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cudaSetDevice

https://visualization.hpc.mil/wiki/Choosing_the_GPU_in_a_Multi-GPU_system

Comment: @Anycorn I've seen the cudaSetDevice(best_gpu); function before, but how do I know which device to use. The example they had was selecting the GPU with the most CUDA cores. I have two identical GTX 560 Ti's. How do I know which one is the one not connected to the monitor based on what you see from the control panel?

Comment: @sel just use cudaSetDevice(1).

Comment: @Anycorn How do you know it's 1?

Comment: @sel I am just guessing.  The default is 0 and if it does not work, then its 1

Comment: @Anycorn Good enough for me, but just out of curiosity, what if I had four GPUs, one hooked to a display and I want CUDA to run on the other 3, then what?!?